# How to allow Scandinavic characters in a checkbox using regex?

Tags: jquery, regex

How to allow Scandinavic characters in a textbox using regex?
I have used the following code. But it does not allow the characters such as `ä` or `ö`

```
var charexp = /^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜ ]+$/;
if(!charexp.test(cus_fname))
{
    $("#cus_fname_div").html("Only characters are allowed.");
}
```

Please help.

Comment: As a Norwegian I'd just like to point out that there's also Æ, Ø and Å. And for our brothers in Iceland, Ý, Þ and Ð.

Comment: What do you mean by 'checkbox', an `<input type="checkbox" />` doesn't contain any characters, except in its `value ` attribute/property.

Comment: Extremely sorry, it will be testbox, I am editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var charexp = /^[a-zA-Z\u00E4\u00F6\u00FC\u00C4\u00D6\u00DC ]+$/;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `"ä".match(/^[a-zA-Z\u{00E4}\u{00F6}\u{00FC}\u{00C4}\u{00D6}\u{00DC} ]+$/);` returns null.

Comment: That fiddle alerts "Only characters are allowed.".

Comment: Ops sorry, you right, remove curly brackets, just updated my answer